# Parsing Facebook JSON feed in php recently blocked?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a PHP script which is parsing a Facebook JSON post feed.
This was working well until a couple of days ago.
The URL and its contents are correct and I have validated the JSON structure.
But my php script does not parse the content anymore.
Is it possible that Facebook might have blocked my page from pulling the feed?
Any way to check?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the official Graph API, or scraping something?

Comment: @ceejayoz I am scraping, using code I found but can’t remember where. I do have a proper Facebook dev token though for the page I am using the posts from.

Comment: Then yes, it's highly possible you've been blocked, as scraping is a violation of their terms of service. I'd bet if you access the JSON endpoint via the server you'll get a page with a captcha or something - they often do this to scrapers. You should use the API.

Comment: @ceejayoz if I paste the JSON url in my browser I do get the feed, without a captcha. I understand I should move to the official API but I was hoping to find a quick fix.

Comment: Is your browser on the same server as the scraper? They have a variety of ways of identifying a robot - user agent, browsing pattern, existence of an otherwise-active Facebook browsing session, etc. What you are doing is *guaranteed* to break at times, if not permanently.

Comment: No the browser is not on the server. I get your point, thanks

Comment: You could try hitting the JSON endpoint *from the server* - hitting a captcha there would almost certainly indicate your server's IP has been detected as a scraper.

Comment: What JSON are you talking about? AFAIK Facebook has removed any JSON feeds quite a while ago already ...